# Using prototype.js to parse and read an XML file in sharepoint 2010 without disabling edit mode

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, prototypejs, editing

I'm working on making a dashboard for my company on sharepoint, involving retrieving information from lists and libraries of other pages in the website collection. I'm using a Corasworks tool (Sharepoint Site List Provider) to retrieve a list of subsites as an XML file, for which I have built some javascript code using 'prototype.js' and my own personal methods to read and parse through the file. I tested the file externally on internet explorer and it works perfectly, retrieving the information I needed. I then tried to implement it on Sharepoint 2010, and it worked nicely, however, when I went back to try to add another web part to my page, I couldn't and then found out the page threw a javascript error which contained the following:

Line:3 
Char: 13993
Error: Type Mismatch
Code: 0
url: (my website url)

I went back and debugged my code line by line to see where it was crashing, and found out the following first line to be the culprit:

```
     <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                                    <script src="flightDashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                    <script>
                                    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ajaxCall");

                                    </script>
```

I did some research of course, and found out that using prototype.js causes some of the microsoft javascript functions to crash because it extends certain information and methods that they use. 
I searched for ways to work around this problem because my supervisor wants me to use prototype.js because of its ease of compatibility between browsers. So far I've come around some very vague answers that were given to people with a similar problem, like the following:

"What about wrapping the script file references with the EditModePanel control so that it only get's rendered when the page is display mode and not edit mode. i.e. 
       < PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel PageDisplayMode="Display" runat=server id="EditModePanel1">put your js references in here < / PublishingWebControls >

" - Michael O' Donovan

However, he didn't specify where to implement this code, so I tried implementing this on my code and when I saved the page in Sharepoint Designer, the web part became invalid and it wasn't of much help.

This has kept me stuck for several days and I really can't find anything to move on, I would really appreciate any information or tips that could help me achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to work around this problem.  PrototypeJS doesn't work very well with other javascript libraries since it makes changes to the way javascript works.  See here:

[How can I use FancyUpload (with mootools) side by side with prototype.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180995/how-can-i-use-fancyupload-with-mootools-side-by-side-with-prototype-js)

PrototypeJS doesn't have a "safe mode" of operation where it doesn't make changes that can cause problems with other libraries.

Your two options are

1) Isolate the prototype.js code inside of an iframe so it doesn't conflict with sharepoint webparts.

2) Switch to another javascript library.  Most sharepoint developer would recommend jQuery.